# SendBroadcast to closed Activity

Tags: android

I have a simple Service which sends broadcasts to two different Activities at the same time

**From Service to Activity 1**

```
Intent BroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity.PrivateServiceReceiver));
BroadcastIntent.SetAction(MainActivity.PrivateServiceReceiver.UPDATE);
BroadcastIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("NAME", _name);
BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("EMAIL", _email);
SendBroadcast(BroadcastIntent);
```

**From Service to Activity 2**

```
Intent BroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(PrivateActivity.SessionServiceReceiver));
BroadcastIntent.SetAction(PrivateActivity.SessionServiceReceiver.UPDATE);
BroadcastIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("NAME", _name);
BroadcastIntent.PutExtra("EMAIL", _email);
SendBroadcast(BroadcastIntent);
```

Activity 1 is the main activity so it receives the broadcast fine where activity 2 can only receive the broadcast once it is opened by the user (regardless if it was `destroy` afterwards).

If activity 2 has never been opened by the user, the app crashes with the following error

> **AndroidRuntime  android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object**

**Error details:**

> at JAVA.PrivateActivity+SessionServiceReceiver.OnReceive
>   (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent)
>   [0x00041] in <2708c0a2041c47f486b793fe75695a20>:0
>
> at
>   Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver.n_OnReceive_Landroid_content_Context_Landroid_content_Intent_
>   (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_context, System.IntPtr native_intent) [0x00019] in
>   :0
>
> at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.16(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> at
>   crc643f2c8e11b2623f14.PrivateActivity_SessionServiceReceiver.n_onReceive(Native
>   Method)
>
> at
>   crc643f2c8e11b2623f14.PrivateActivity_SessionServiceReceiver.onReceive(PrivateMessage_SessionServiceReceiver.java:29)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3788)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:219)
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

*`JAVA.` is my app name, please don't confuse it with `java` namespace.*

`PrivateActivity` **receiver** as following

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class SessionServiceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {
    public static readonly string SESSION_SERVICE_STARTED = "SESSION_SERVICE_STARTED";
    public static readonly string UPDATE = "UPDATE";           

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        if (intent.Action == SESSION_SERVICE_STARTED){
            Log.Info(TAG, "SESSION STARTED");
        }
        else if (intent.Action == UPDATE){
            Log.Info(TAG, "SESSION UPDATE RECIEVED");      
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to tackle this issue?

Comment: Can you also paste `PrivateActivity` class, i think you add receiver class as static.

Comment: updated the post :) thanks